# Install numpy for blender

Tags: python, linux, numpy, pip, blender

I'm having a hard time exporting my blender model to glTF 2.0 format (for godot):

[image]

(I still can export it to default .dae format)

So, I tried installing numpy for all of my python3 versions (python3, python3.6, python3.9) :

```
python<versions> -m pip install numpy
```

[image]

After restarting blender, I still have this message.

I tried using blender integrated python (3.9) shell to install numpy, with no more luck:

[image]

What do I do now?

[image]

Comment: If you do `python<versions> -m pip list` , is the module listed ?

Comment: Yes, it's still listed. Well, I installed a different version of blender and it's working now. I guess it was some kind of packaging problem.

Answer (score 10):

The following reply from [GitHub](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/109#issuecomment-779712733) did it for me!

```sh
sudo apt -y install python3-numpy
```

I installed Blender via `Ubuntu (deb)` from the Pop!_Shop on Pop OS.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Install python3.2
2. Install numpy for python3.2 using the python3.2 command instead of python
3. on my system numpy was located in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages. Copy numpy from there to blender/2.57/scripts/modules

Comment: Why would you install such an ancient version of Python? This might be correct, but please provide some supporting information about why it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually blender has built-in python module and usually it contains Numpy.
In case you want to make sure, blender's python module can be found in `/blender/<BUILD_VERSION>/<BLENDER_VERSION>/python/bin/pythonX`.
Thus install Numpy with system python won't work.

For example if you install blender with snap recently.
python path will be `/snap/blender/206/2.93/python/bin/python3.9`

I would recommend install blender again with another way.

remove current blender `sudo dpkg -r blender`

snap `sudo snap install blender --classic`

then `cd /snap/blender/2106` (number may differ depending on version) and './blender' in terminal to run blender

How did you install your blender by the way?